# CC2538 - sending/receiving bulk data using libusb-win32

Tags: c#, usb, microcontroller, libusb, libusb-win32

In short what my general aim is: I want to send bulk data from my CC2538EM via USB to the PC. And there the data is ought to be read using a C# application.

As I could not install TI's CDC Driver of the "CC2538 firmware foundation" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258769/ti-cc2538-usb-cdc-driver-issue)), I decided to try to use libusb-win32 instead (And LibUsbDotNet for MS Visual Studio).

But the data I write from neither host nor device can't either be read or written.

The usb descriptor:

```
const USB_DESCRIPTOR usbDescriptor = {
{ // device
    sizeof(USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR),
    USB_DESC_TYPE_DEVICE,           // bDescriptorType
    0x0200,                         // bcdUSB (USB 2.0)
    0x02,                           // bDeviceClass (CDC)
    0x00,                           // bDeviceSubClass
    0x00,                           // bDeviceProtocol
    USB_EP0_PACKET_SIZE,            // bMaxPacketSize0
    0x0451,                         // idVendor (Texas Instruments)
    0x16C8,                         // idProduct (CC2538 CDC)
    0x0100,                         // bcdDevice (v1.0)
    0x01,                           // iManufacturer
    0x02,                           // iProduct
    0x00,                           // iSerialNumber
    0x01,                           // bNumConfigurations
},
    { // configuration0
        sizeof(USB_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR),
        USB_DESC_TYPE_CONFIG,           // bDescriptorType
        SIZEOF_CONFIGURATION0_DESC,     // wTotalLength
        0x02,                           // bNumInterfaces
        0x01,                           // bConfigurationValue
        0x00,                           // iConfiguration
        0xA0,                           // bmAttributes (7,4-0: res, 6: self-powered, 5: remote wakeup)
        25                              // bMaxPower (max 2 * 25 = 50 mA)
    },
        { // interface0
            sizeof(USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR),
            USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,        // bDescriptorType
            0x00,                           // bInterfaceNumber
            0x00,                           // bAlternateSetting (none)
            0x01,                           // bNumEndpoints
            0x02,                           // bInterfaceClass (CDC communication interface)
            0x02,                           // bInterfaceSubClass (Abstract control model)
            0x01,                           // bInterfaceProcotol (V25TER)
            0x00                            // iInterface
        },
            { // hdrFunc0
                sizeof(USBCDC_HEADER_FUNC_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_CS_INTERFACE,     // bDescriptorType
                USBCDC_FUNCDESC_HEADER,         // bDescriptorSubType
                0x0110                          // bcdCDC
            },
            { // absCallMgmtFunc0
                sizeof(USBCDC_ABSTRACT_CTRL_MGMT_FUNC_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_CS_INTERFACE,     // bDescriptorType
                USBCDC_FUNCDESC_ABS_CTRL_MGMT,  // bDescriptorSubType
                0x02                            // bmCapabilities (supported class requests)
            },
            { // unionIfFunc0
                sizeof(USBCDC_UNION_INTERFACE_FUNC_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_CS_INTERFACE,     // bDescriptorType
                USBCDC_FUNCDESC_UNION_IF,       // bDescriptorSubType
                0x00,                           // bMasterInterface
                0x01                            // bSlaveInterface0
            },
            { // callMgmtFunc0
                sizeof(USBCDC_CALL_MGMT_FUNC_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_CS_INTERFACE,     // bDescriptorType
                USBCDC_FUNCDESC_CALL_MGMT,      // bDescriptorSubType
                0x00,                           // bmCapabilities
                0x01                            // bDataInterface
            },
            { // endpoint0
                sizeof(USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,         // bDescriptorType
                0x82,                           // bEndpointAddress
                USB_EP_ATTR_INT,                // bmAttributes (INT)
                0x0040,                         // wMaxPacketSize
                0x40                            // bInterval (64 full-speed frames = 64 ms)
            },
        { // interface1
            sizeof(USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR),
            USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,        // bDescriptorType
            0x01,                           // bInterfaceNumber
            0x00,                           // bAlternateSetting (none)
            0x02,                           // bNumEndpoints
            0x02,                           // bInterfaceClass (CDC data interface)
            0x00,                           // bInterfaceSubClass (none)
            0x00,                           // bInterfaceProcotol (no protocol)
            0x00                            // iInterface
        },
            { // endpoint1
                sizeof(USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,         // bDescriptorType
                0x84,                           // bEndpointAddress
                USB_EP_ATTR_BULK,               // bmAttributes (BULK)
                0x0040,                         // wMaxPacketSize
                0x00                            // bInterval
            },
            { // endpoint2
                sizeof(USB_ENDPOINT_DESCRIPTOR),
                USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,         // bDescriptorType
                0x04,                           // bEndpointAddress
                USB_EP_ATTR_BULK,               // bmAttributes (BULK)
                0x0040,                         // wMaxPacketSize
                0x00                            // bInterval
            },
{ // strings
    { // langIds
        sizeof(USB_STRING_0_DESCRIPTOR),
        USB_DESC_TYPE_STRING,
        0x0409 // English US
    },
    { // manufacturer
        sizeof(USB_STRING_1_DESCRIPTOR),
        USB_DESC_TYPE_STRING,
        'T', 'e', 'x', 'a', 's', ' ', 'I', 'n', 's', 't', 'r', 'u', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't', 's'
    },
    { // product
        sizeof(USB_STRING_2_DESCRIPTOR),
        USB_DESC_TYPE_STRING,
        'C', 'C', '2', '5', '3', '8', ' ', 'U', 'S', 'B', ' ', 'C', 'D', 'C'
    }
}
```

};

The data I read/write on the device that way:

```
int main(void)
{

    initBoard();

    usbCdcInit(57600);  // Enable the USB interface


    memset(&usbCdcInBufferData, 0x00, sizeof(USB_EPIN_RINGBUFFER_DATA));
    usbCdcInBufferData.pBuffer = pInBuffer;
    usbCdcInBufferData.size = sizeof(pInBuffer);
    usbCdcInBufferData.endpointReg = USB_F4;
    usbCdcInBufferData.endpointIndex = 4;
    usbCdcInBufferData.endpointSize = 64;
    memset(&usbCdcOutBufferData, 0x00, sizeof(USB_EPOUT_RINGBUFFER_DATA));
    usbCdcOutBufferData.pBuffer = pOutBuffer;
    usbCdcOutBufferData.size = sizeof(pOutBuffer);
    usbCdcOutBufferData.endpointReg = USB_F4;
    usbCdcOutBufferData.endpointIndex = 4;



    uint8_t test[10];

    while (1)
    {
        //
        // Process USB events
        //
        usbProcessEvents();


        uint8_t test2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        uint16_t testLength = 10;

        usbobufPop(&usbCdcOutBufferData, test, testLength);
        usbibufPush(&usbCdcInBufferData, test2, testLength);

}
```

}

And for the host I used the LibUsbDotNot read/write example:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  LibUsbDotNet
        ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

        try
        {
            // Find and open the usb device.
            MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

            // If the device is open and ready
            if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

            // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
            // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
            // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
            // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
            // configuration and interface selection.
            IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
            {
                // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
                // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

                // Select config #1
                if (!wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1))
                    Console.Write("error setting config failed");

                // Claim interface #1.
                if (!wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(1))
                    Console.Write("error: claiming interface failed");

            }
            Console.Write("");

            // open read endpoint 1.
            UsbEndpointReader reader = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep04);

            // openwrite enpoint
            UsbEndpointWriter writer = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep04);

            int bytesWritten;
            String cmdLine = "blablub";
            ec = writer.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cmdLine), 2000, out bytesWritten);
            if (ec != ErrorCode.None) throw new Exception(UsbDevice.LastErrorString);



            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

            while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
            {
                int bytesRead;

                Console.WriteLine();

                // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 5 seconds,
                // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur. 
                ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 50000, out bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}: No more bytes!", ec));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytesRead);

                // Write that output to the console.
                Console.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MyUsbDevice != null)
            {
                if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
                {
                    // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
                    // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
                    // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
                    // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
                    // configuration and interface selection.
                    IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                    {
                        // Release interface #0.
                        wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(1);
                    }

                    MyUsbDevice.Close();
                }
                MyUsbDevice = null;

                // Free usb resources
                UsbDevice.Exit();

            }

        }
    }
```

So far:

- the configuration #1 can be set
- the interface #1 can be claimed
- endpointInfo shows, that is endpoint chosen correctly

but trying to read / write in the C# application always leads to an "IOTimedOut" Error.

So I wonder what I might bedoing wrong and if it is even possible to make the cc2538 work with libusb-win32.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Your USB descriptor on the device looks wrong.   Interface 1 has endpoint 4 as both IN and OUT.  I'm mildly surprised it enumerated without error.

Comment: Why use libusb-win32?  It's really old, and requires you to use a specific driver for the device.  libusb 1.0 is newer and can work with WinUSB and other drivers.

Comment: @RussSchultz but both have got different endpoint addresses, so they can be distinguished, can't they? I found at lot of examples using the same endpoint for IN and OUT.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've tried to install a driver according to that instructions: http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend but neither the WinUSB driver could be installed nor did the Zadig.exe work to create a driver...

Comment: @alogheo  I don't think they have separate endpoint addresses.  They're both "interface 1, endpoint 4".  one is marked as bulk in, the other bulk out.    The upper bit in the endpoint address is the designation of in/out.

Comment: I did now change the IN endpoint to number 3, but that has changed nothing..